# How do you retrieve nested Sets?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Is there an annotation I'm missing or is this a limitation to hibernate retrieval?

Entities:

```
class A {
   Long id;
   Set<B> b;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")
   public Set<B> getBs() {
      return b;
   }

}

class B {
   Long id;
   Set<C> c;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinTable(name = "B_C", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "C_ID")
   public Set<C> getCs() {
      return C;
   }

}
```

DAOs:

```
class ADaoImpl {    
   public A load(Long id) {
      return new A((A) session.load(A.class, id);
   }
}
```

When I attempt to load an A, I get a

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.getLoadedCollectionOwnerOrNull(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:853)
```

Comment: what Hibernate version are you using?

Comment: also please post the full stack trace (at least up to your own code).

Comment: Anyway it looks like Hibernate bug to me. I searched their bug DB but nothing with NPE in `StatefulPersistenceContext.java:853`. You could file a bug then.

Answer (score 8):

I had an issue very similar to this were i had nested sets, and the hashCode methods for each showed up in the stack trace.  In the hashCode methods, they referred to each other, so I removed the reference to each object in the hashcode methods, and I no longer got this exceptions

Comment: There's Set in my class too and resolved same Exception by removing the reference each other in HashCode and Equals.

Comment: what did you replace it with?

Comment: Thank you so much, I had a `@Data` from lombok and it was generating my `hashCode` method using all the properties. I just added `@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"mySet"})` and it worked !

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not the complete exception right?

Where is the setter in class A?
The b collection in class A is friendly scoped then hibernate will not be able to write/inject it's value.
The same goes for the C collection in class B.

Please, copy your hibernate.xml and any other configuration class here. The hibernate/java version are important too.

Comment: This is the right exception. And you can assume that the DAOs are working correctly otherwise and have all necessary getter and setter methods

Comment: If it only were the lack of an appropriate setter, Hibernate wouldn't throw NPE...

Comment: I don't know why are you saying that, but if it's true, it would still be Hibernate bug. (unless Hibernate documents this behavior - which it probably doesn't).